# IE8 toggleClass not working properly

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, toggleclass

Well I have a menu and there I want to have an class called `active`, when its active, obviously.

To toggle this class I am using the jQuery toggle function, but it does just activate it in the js element. If I check the dom element, this class is never set. But I need this class, because of my CSS styles.

I know that there are already many topics about `toggleClass` jQuery, but they doesn't fit (at least I couldn't find anything suitable)

Here some code:

```
$('#menu').on('click', '.tab span', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $tab = $(this).parent('.tab');
    $tab.siblings('.tab.active').removeClass('active');
    $tab.toggleClass('active');
});
```

HTML markup

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="tab">
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Its working in all browsers, except IE8
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? how are you testing that the class isn't being applied?

Comment: Havn't tested this theory, but I seem to recall a similar issue and solving with something like having a "base" class to "alternate/toggle" with my "active" class. Try something like that, I "think" it might help. Been a long time since I've seen the issue, but I do recall it, and I swear I handled it with something like `.toggleClass("base active")` where base was dropped while active was added or vice versa.

Comment: Also, since you're using "removeClass" the way you are, you have no "real need" for `toggleClass` here. You would do just as well to replace that line with `addClass`. And the line `$tab.siblings('.tab.active').removeClass('active');` is not going to remove active from itself ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('#menu').on('click', '.tab span', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $tab = $(this).parent('.tab');
    $tab.addClass('active').siblings('.tab').removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#menu').on('click', '.tab span', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $tab = $(this).parent('.tab');

    // remove active from all tabs
    $('#menu .tab').removeClass('active');

    // make current tab as active
    $tab.addClass('active');
});
```