# javascript code not working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer

This is a icon for menu to open on click and close. On Chrome works perfect (Firefox and Opera too) but on IE is a problem (menu is always opened and nothing happen on click). The version of IE is IE11 ( [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtXFn.jpg) [IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAPO4.jpg)
2pictures) jquery version-3.2.1.

HTML

```
<div class="menu-toggle">
        <div class="mini"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu-toggle {
    padding: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: .8em;
    right: .5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: silver;
}

.mini,
.mini::before,
.mini::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    height: 3px;
    width: 1.75em;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}

.mini::before {
    transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.mini::after {
    transform: translateY(3px);
}

.open .mini {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.open .mini::before {
    opacity: 0;
}

.open .mini::after {
    transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

JS

```
$(".menu-toggle").click(function () {
      $(".site-nav").toggleClass("site-nav-open");
      $(this).toggleClass("open");
});
```

Comment: what is a problem ?

Comment: In order to get help, you need to state what the problem is. Does the click event fire? Does the classes get added? Is it an issue with the CSS or HTML which we do not see? And what version of IE?

Comment: for that matter, what version of jquery?

Comment: There must be 1000 of reason why this code is not working. That question is not clear. Please, be more specific and add the error that you got and the version of the libraries that you are using. Otherwise, it seem that you are asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please check these links to learn [How to write effective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sry I'm new in this...i will give all informations what you need

Comment: @AntonioJagodić, you're doing just fine. StackOverflow does have conventions to follow, but you'll get the hang of how to ask questions and what info to provide. Don't be discouraged! People here like to help. As to your menu issue, can you show us the markup and CSS for the menu itself? (The markup that has the .site-nav class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve a problem...it was on css .site-nav (display). Ty all for respond.

Answer (score -1):

Check this solution [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671917/ie8-toggleclass-not-working-properly) and try using the code below.

```
$(this).addClass('open').siblings(this).removeClass('open');
```

I hope you will find this solution helpful